# I am getting issue for connecting to Azure, i am not sure what to do now

Tags: authentication, terraform, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

Explain me What is actually wrong with It?
I am getting issue for connecting to Azure, i am not sure what to do now. i tried using right ids and keys as both as Contributor and Administrator. How to mitigate it.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  client_id       = "I have Right Keys Here"
  client_secret   = "I have Right Keys Here"
  tenant_id       = "I have Right Keys Here"
  subscription_id = "I have Right Keys Here"

}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "JAVA11RG" {
  name     = "JAVA"
  location = "South India"
}
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "Javatomcat" {
  name                = "M11-JAVA-plan"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.JAVA11RG.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.JAVA11RG.location

  sku {
    tier = "Basic"
    size = "B1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "TOMCAT" {
  name                = "JAVATomcat"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.JAVA11RG.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.JAVA11RG.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_app_service_plan.Javatomcat.id

  site_config {
    always_on = true
    application_stack {
      java_server         = "TOMCAT"
      java_server_version = "9.0"
      java_version        = "11"
    }

  }

  app_settings = {
    "WEBSITE_JAVA_OPTS" = "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true"
    "TOMCAT_VERSION"    = "9.0.0.0"
  }

  connection_string {
    name  = "Database"
    type  = "SQLServer"
    value = ""
  }
}
resource "azurerm_mysql_server" "DBServer11" {
  name                = "example-mysqlserver"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.JAVA11RG.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.JAVA11RG.name

  administrator_login          = "admin"
  administrator_login_password = "admin"

  sku_name   = "GP_Gen5_2"
  storage_mb = 5120
  version    = "5.7"

  auto_grow_enabled                 = true
  backup_retention_days             = 7
  geo_redundant_backup_enabled      = true
  infrastructure_encryption_enabled = true
  public_network_access_enabled     = true
  ssl_enforcement_enabled           = true
  ssl_minimal_tls_version_enforced  = "TLS1_2
}

resource "azurerm_mysql_database" "DB11" {
  name                = "Tomdb"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.JAVA11RG.name
  server_name         = azurerm_mysql_server.DBServer11.name
  charset             = "utf8"
  collation           = "utf8_unicode_ci"
}
```

############################################################################################
Error: building account: attempting to discover object ID for authenticated service principal with client ID "963ce430-2581-486d-941c-fb618ddbbb74": executing request: unexpected status 401 with error: Authorization_IdentityNotFound: The identity of the calling application could not be established.
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"],
│   on main.tf line 1, in provider "azurerm":
│    1: provider "azurerm" {

Comment: It's possible that the account you're using doesn't have the correct permission. Are you able to log using `az login --service-principal -u CLIENT_ID -p CLIENT_SECRET --tenant TENANT_ID`? And able to `az vm list-sizes --location westus`? Also did you give the account contributor role for that subscription?  You may have multiple subscription ID, make sure you selected the correct one.

Comment: it could also be due to the delay in Azure after granting the account with contributor/administrator role. Not sure if you need to relogin with `az login` and see if the client secret has changed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems ***client_certificate*** is missing in your configuration

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  client_id       = "I have Right Keys Here"
  client_secret   = "I have Right Keys Here"
  client_certificate_path = "certificate path"
  client_certificate_password = "password"
  tenant_id       = "I have Right Keys Here"
  subscription_id = "I have Right Keys Here"

}
```

Refer below Doc for more details https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_certificate